# Bluetooth issues with Microsoft 6000 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit

I can't get the keyboard to connect at ALL. I've tried both the default Bluetooth install via the graphical interface and installed bluez-gnome as well.

```
sudo hidd --connect

sudo hidd --search hcitool scan
```

Doesn't work either. When doing search the keyboard is found, but won't connect.

The keyboard connects fine in Windows and OSX using the same Bluetooth USB dongle.

Update 1: I am going to try: http://www.siamnet.org/Wiki/Ubuntu-AppleBluetoothKeyboard

Will update here if any updates. If anyone has a suggestion I welcome it.

Comment: same here with 11.10. I made it work after trying many times the pairing, but after idle time it stops working again and I have to start the pairing all over. Any luck with blueman?

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.